# store data in matrix from loop in r

Tags: r

Unable to store "movement" in the matrix. It only stores the option where movement is "non-moving." This is a small portion of the code. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the whole code. Sorry about that but it may help. The data is processes is raw GPS data e.g
Record Number Date  Time  Lat  Long  Speed  Altitude

Hi Gregor, thanks for your comments. I have added the whole code now, sorry, I missed out the top part where all the sources are for the functions. Unfortunately it relies on a few. There is a problem with historyLength so thanks for that. However, shouldn't I still be able to save the output to the matrix? The code (as is) still runs ok.

```
library(pracma)
library(zoo)


# Path fo file of raw GPS output
R<-read.csv("F://Cow1//R.csv") 

# path to distance function
source ("F://R functions//Distfunc.R")

# path to absolute heading function
source ("F://R functions//AbsHeading.R")

# path to Movement type function
source ("F://R functions//MovementType.R")

# path to bayes filter function
source ("F://R functions//bayesFilter.R")


# attach data
attach (R)






#Threshold for altitude
altThreshold <- 0.60 #0.6m threshold?

#Threshold angle for determining movement
angleThreshold <-40 #40 degrees

#Minimum speed for determining movement #0.3 m/s
minSpeed <-0.3

#Number of instances to consider as part of the Bayes inference
historyLength <-4

#Sampling period for GPS receiver
GPSSample <- 5 #5 second interval between samples 

#Fix accuracy of the GPS receiver
GPS_accy <-0.6 #0.6 metres

###############################################

########## Thresholds and Parameters Segmentation ###########

segmentSize <- 32 #32 movement objects per 'segment'

################################################

#Previous heading in order to work out track (left, right, forward, etc.)
previousHeading <- 0

#extract the instances, then the feature values for lat and long
#...then do calcs




lst <- list() # temporary list to store the results
for (i in seq(1, nrow(R) - 1)){ # loop through each row of the 'R' matrix
  lat1 <- deg2rad(R[i, 4])
  long1 <- deg2rad(R[i, 5])
  lat2 <- deg2rad(R[i + 1, 4])
  long2 <- deg2rad(R[i + 1, 5])
  gcd_vif <- gcd.vif(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)

  # calc estimated speed by mean of speeds between two GPS records
  estSpeed <- (R[i, 6] + R[i+1, 6])/2

  # calculate acceleration (velocity)
  accel <- (R[i+1, 6] - R[i, 6]) / GPSSample

  # calculate absolute heading 
  heading <- absoluteHeading(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)

  # calculate bearing relative to previous GPS record
  relAngle <- 0
  # if the number of GPS records is less than 3 then no change in track
  if (i < 1) relAngle = heading
  # otherwise consider the previous heading in order to calculate the    new track
 else if (i > 0) {
 relAngle = (previousHeading - heading)

}


 # determine whether movement is occurring and if so what type
 # if there are insufficient history items then just record movement   types discretely
 if (i < historyLength) movement <- movementType(relAngle,    angleThreshold)

 else if (i > historyLength-1) {
 # Array to store speeds
 speedHistory <- array(historyLength)
 n = historyLength-1
 # get the speeds from the previous n (hisoryLength) "Movements" 
 for (j in seq(1, length(historyLength))){
  speedHistory [n] = R[i-j, 6]
  n-1
  }

   if (!bayesFilter(speedHistory, minSpeed, GPS_accy)) movement <- "non-moving" 
   else if(bayesFilter(speedHistory, minSpeed, GPS_accy)) movement <- movementType(relAngle, angleThreshold)

 }

  holder <- matrix(data = movement, nrow = nrow(R), ncol = 1) 




 # update previous heading information
 previousHeading = heading






  # Store the input data and the results
 lst[[i]] <- c(
  latitude_position_1 = lat1, 
  longtude_position_1 = long1, 
  longtude_position_2 = long2, 
  Distance = gcd_vif,
  Speed = estSpeed,
  Acceleration = accel,
  Absolute_Heading = heading,
  Relative_Heading = relAngle,
  Movement = movement




)




}  
Results <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst)) # store the input data and the results in a data frame
Results
```

Comment: This is hard to tell since you don't share a single piece of data. I assume that `historyLength` is a single number because you treat it that way in your `if` statements. Let's say it's 5. I don't think `array(5)` is what you want for `speedHistory`, and it also means `for(j in seq(1, length(historyLength))` becomes `for (j in 1)` and `speedHistory[n]` presumably extends your array of length 1 with a lot of NAs.

Comment: I think you need to run your code one line at a time, your for loops one iteration at a time, and make sure everything does what you think it does. But unless you share with use sample values for `historyLength`, `relAngle`, `angleThreshold`, and everything else you use, the best we can do is guess.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to choke up the post. I will add the rest.

Comment: Just to say, the code runs fine, but I cannot store 'movement' in the matrix

Comment: Even if I try to store another object e.g. estSpeed to the matrix e.g holder <- matrix(data = estSpeed, nrow = nrow(R), ncol = 1) it still gives a matrix filled with the first value in the loop only. Do I need a for loop before the matrix to fill it at each iteration of the initial for loop?

Comment: Couldn't run your code, `object R not found`. Try running it in a fresh R session. What would be great is if you could *simplify* the code to isolate the problem. How much of this can you delete and still have show what you're stuck on (but also still have it run)?

Comment: I'm also still **very** skeptical about the items in my first comment. You seem to sometimes treat `historyLength` as a long vector, and sometimes as a single number. Figure out which it should be, which it is, and be consistent.